# Why can you have a th element without thead element?

Tags: html

I know that the browsers are very flexible with html, but is there any other reason why this is possible?

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Column 1
        </th>
    </tr>
<table>
```

Comment: Why should you not be able to have it?

Comment: Isn't that the 'normal' way to use it?

Comment: I thought that was not valid.

Comment: What do you think is the problem with the html you have provided?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<th>` doesn't necessarly mean it's in the head of the table. For example, you might have this layout:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name:</th>
    <td>Tarquin Smith</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Occupation:</th>
    <td>Jovian Agent</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you use thead and have the same layout?

Comment: Absolutely. Just as long as it makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

`<thead>` contains rows. long story short it just says that that row is the head row. i dont use it but it just makes it easier to use it in your css. for example:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Savings</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
```

and your css could say: `thead {color:green;}`

`<th>` is for one cell in your table and all it does is bold and center the text in it.

Comment: "bold and center" refers to default styles, of course. Completely overrideable by CSS.

Comment: true, you should check both tags on w3schools

Comment: [No you shouldn't](http://w3fools.com/)

Comment: i see your point but the only reason why i use/recommend w3schools is that you can play around with the code and see what happens...
it doesn't matter who or what made it

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ is significantly better for that.

Comment: i see... it is great for js
but nothing for the rest